# How to partition the drive in linux centOS

Tags: centos, partition

The command df -h says following

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       18G  3.3G   14G  20% /
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 506M     0  506M   0% /dev/shm
```

I want to create the new partition

also when i do `fdisk /dev/sda1` then it says device not loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

You want the disk (/dev/sda) not the first partition (/dev/sda1).  This will be outside the lvm stuff that you are using for your root volume

You are using LVM (Logical Volume Manager).  You have Logical volume in a Volume group VolGroup00.  If you want to add a volume to the volume group you will have to use pvdisplay to find out how much space is used on the physical device and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create the new partition

Your system is using LVM, so start with the man page for `lvm(8)` and read its references (especially `lvcreate`).

> also when i do fdisk /dev/sda1 then it says device not loaded

`fdisk` works on block devices, not on partitions. Try `fdisk /dev/sda`.

Answer (score 0):

Use vgdisplay to find if there is any more space. If so you can create a partition. I would first mount it on /mnt and copy everything over.

e.g. if you are going to create /tmp

vgdisplay (find space available)
lvcreate (create LVM)
mkfs [lv] (create filesystem)
mount [lv] /mnt
mv /tmp/* /mnt/
mv /tmp/.??* /mnt/
umount /mnt
mount [lv] /tmp

Kind of thing

If vgdisplay shows you have no space available, you will need to boot into a rescue mode off install dvd, reduce the / filesystem, then reduce the LV, then you will have space to create a new LV

That's a little trickier.  See my blog post for more details on that portion
http://geekswing.com/geek/reducing-filesystem-fs-size-and-lvm-size-in-linux/